# Augmented and Coefficient rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I am confused by these 2 terms. Augmented rank and coefficient rank are they refer to the same thing or different? I know that that to find the rank of a matrix I have to reduce it to Echelon form first and then count the non-zero row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coefficient matrix only contains the coefficients of the variables of the linear equations. "Augmented" refers to the addition of a column (usually separated by a vertical line) of the constant terms of the linear equations.

For instance, given the system

\begin{align*}
x+2y&=-3\\
-3x+y&=1
\end{align*}

the coefficient matrix is

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\ -3 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

while the augmented matrix is

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 2 & -3\\
-3 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right].$$

Comment: oh I see that! ok now how can I find the rank of the coefficient matrix ?Counting the non-zero without reduce it to Echelon form?

Comment: In general you cannot determine the rank of a matrix without reducing it to row echelon form. If it is in row echelon form, just count the number of non-zero rows.

Comment: got it. Thank you very much